# Log On To Restriction keeps resetting in Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

We have Windows Essential Business Server 2008 up and running after upgrading from a Windows 2003 domain. Everything is working fine, except new users! Every time I add a new user, I set the log on to restrictions to allow them to log into any computer. As soon as they log into one machine and then log out, the now get restricted to just the servers in our domain, not any of the workstations. I can't seem to find a policy that has this setting. How do I get this to not reset those log on to restrictions?

Comment: Have you run RSOP.msc against the system/user in question to ensure no preventative policies are being set?

Comment: I ran it against his account and it shows that the Allow Log on Locally is set to Domain Users. The problem isn't in that machine, it's in the actual user account. If I set it to say that they can log onto All Computers, the next time they log off from any machine in the building, it gets set back to a restriction to just server machines. I don't see anything off hand that would do this in RSOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. I didn't assign any CALs to the 3 new users I added. As I assigned the licenses, the setting was set back to All Computers.